# Ruby using FbGraph gem :: get friends' email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

i'm trying to get friends' email address using FbGraph gem.
i found somewhere that it said i can get them by 'email' object, so i tried but nothing happened. here is my code and..

```
me= FbGraph::User.me( @access_token )
@friends= me.friends

@friends.each do |f|
  puts f.email
end
```

is anybody know how i can get friends' email address from facebook by using Ruby FbGraph gem?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you are missing the fetch for the user

```
@friends.each do |f|
  friend = FbGraph::User.fetch(f, :access_token => @access_token)
  puts friend.email
end
```

There should also be a way to fetch a list of users rather than doing a call per user

Comment: ahh... actually it works right but, i get 'null' value. 
should i configure other things?

Comment: I believe it has to do with the privacy settings of the user, it can be a null value. Also does you app have email permission? i believe thats something you need to request

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Facebook docs now say this:
"Note: There is no way for apps to obtain email addresses for a user's friends."

source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/